# Can python private variables even be changed without using object._className__attributeName?

Tags: python, class, private

consider the following code:

```
class animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

class dog(animal):
    def __init__(self, owner, name):
        self.__owner = owner
        super(dog, self).__init__(name)

terrier = dog('A', 'B')
terrier.owner = 'C'
terrier.name = 'D'
print(terrier._dog__owner, terrier._animal__name)
print(terrier.owner, terrier.name)
```

The output is:

```
A B
C D
```

I understand that Python private variables are only protected by convention. But all other threads mention ._className__attributeName eg. terrier._dog__owner as the only way of altering variable values. Here I am able to alter them even using terrier.owner or terrier.name.

Strangely, both give a different output as shown above. So do terrier.owner or terrier.name create different instances from terrier._dog__name or terrier._animal__name? What exactly has happened here?

Comment: Yes. There are no private attributes in Python.

Comment: Yes, `terrier.owner` is a different name from `terrier._dog__owner`.  Why would you think otherwise?  It's no different from doing `terrier.blah = "foo"`.  You can create whatever attributes you want.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain why the two separate instances of object terrier are being created that give two different sets of outputs?

Comment: @AnanyaChandra: you didn't create two separate instances..

Comment: @AnanyaChandra: all you did was add additional attributes. Those are *independent* from the double-underscore attributes.

Comment: ^^Oh okay got it. Thanks.

Comment: @AnanyaChandra: you did not have a `terrier.owner` before, so it wasn't *changed*, no. You *added* those attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-underscore variables are indeed *not private* the way Java or C++ see privacy. They are not meant to be seen as private to code outside the class. They are used to *avoid name clashes among subclasses*, which is why the classname is used as a prefix.

E.g. when you have an internal  implementation for a class `Foo`, and you don't want the subclass `Bar(Foo)` to accidentally use the same names in their implementation, you can use the attribute `__spam`, which will be transformed to `_Foo__spam` and `_Bar__spam` respectively, and thus won't clash.

The `terrier.owner` and `terrier.name` attributes you added are *independent* and have nothing to do with the `_dog__owner` and `_animal__name` attributes used by your classes. Using double-underscore variable names does not prevent other attributes from being created, including the same name without underscores.

Comment: Coming from Java I thought terrier.__owner is a private version of terrier.owner. They are independent though with no relation whatsoever. Got it.